# OpenCV, equalize histogram of image contour

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I know that it is possible to equalize the histogram of an image like:

```
equalizeHist(image, image);
```

and if I want I can define a roi and equalize just this roi in the image:

```
Mat aux3 = image.clone();
equalizeHist(image(Rect(0,100, 200,200)), aux3(Rect(0,100, 200,200)));
```

What I would like to do now (and I don't know if it is possible), is to define a Roi(contour) using a vector of points (cv::vector contour) and equalize this roi (this roi not always will be a rectangle)

So, The question here is:

Is it possible to equalize a portion of the image that is not a rectangle using openCV functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no builtin function in OpenCV to perform histogram equalization with a mask. Still you can write your custom one.

---

**Get a grayscale image:**

```
// Load image
Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

// Convert to grayscale
Mat1b gray;
cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

[image]

**Form a mask from your points:**

```
// Your vector of points
vector<Point> pts = { Point(300, 180), Point(450, 150), Point(600, 200), Point(650, 350), Point(300,300) };

// Create the mask
Mat1b mask(img.rows, img.cols, uchar(0));
vector<vector<Point>> ptsarray{pts};
fillPoly(mask, ptsarray, Scalar(255));
```

[image]

**Call your custom function `equalizeHistWithMask` that equalize the image with a mask:**

```
// Equalize with mask
Mat1b equalized;
equalizeHistWithMask(gray, equalized, mask);
```

[image]

**Here the full code for reference, with the `equalizeHistWithMask` function:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void equalizeHistWithMask(const Mat1b& src, Mat1b& dst, Mat1b mask = Mat1b())
{
    int cnz = countNonZero(mask);
    if (mask.empty() || ( cnz == src.rows*src.cols))
    {
        equalizeHist(src, dst);
        return;
    }

    dst = src.clone();

    // Histogram
    vector<int> hist(256,0);
    for (int r = 0; r < src.rows; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < src.cols; ++c) {
            if (mask(r, c)) {
                hist[src(r, c)]++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Cumulative histogram
    float scale = 255.f / float(cnz);
    vector<uchar> lut(256);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hist.size(); ++i) {
        sum += hist[i];
        lut[i] = saturate_cast<uchar>(sum * scale);
    }

    // Apply equalization
    for (int r = 0; r < src.rows; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < src.cols; ++c) {
            if (mask(r, c)) {
                dst(r, c) = lut[src(r,c)];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Convert to grayscale
    Mat1b gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // Your vector of points
    vector<Point> pts = { Point(300, 180), Point(450, 150), Point(600, 200), Point(650, 350), Point(300,300) };

    // Create the mask
    Mat1b mask(img.rows, img.cols, uchar(0));
    vector<vector<Point>> ptsarray{pts};
    fillPoly(mask, ptsarray, Scalar(255));

    // Equalize with mask
    Mat1b equalized;
    equalizeHistWithMask(gray, equalized, mask);

    imshow("Gray", gray);
    imshow("Mask", mask);
    imshow("Equalized", equalized);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

**Credits**

The code is based on [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/29072/i-need-an-equalization-function-with-mask-like-this-equalizehistsrc-dst-mask/) question on *answers.opencv.org*